# Null Pointer Except, but why?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting a nullpointerexception when I run my program using these two methods:

```
public static String getType(int x)
{
    Contact_Type Type;
    String strType = "";

    Type = AddyBook.get(x).getContactType();
    strType = Type.toString ( );
    return strType;
}

public static String displayByType(String type)
{
    int i = 0;
    String strTypeList = "";

    if(type.equals(null))
        strTypeList = "What?What?What?LOLOLOLOLOLnopechucktesta";
    while(i < AddyBook.size())
    {
        if(getType(i).equalsIgnoreCase(type))
        {
            strTypeList += getType(i);
            strTypeList += "\n";
        }
        i++;
    }
    return strTypeList;
}
```

The lines that I'm being pointed to are

```
strType = Type.toString ( );
```

and

```
if(getType(i).equalsIgnoreCase(type))
```

I'm also getting the exception in other methods that are identical except for the variable they're operating on.

My issue is that in my driver class I tested the "getType" method directly, and it worked properly. Then, in the "displayByType" method I even say "if Type is null, do this," but it still just throws the exception. I have no clue why, but I feel like it's probably really simple and obvious; I've just been working on this for too long to see it right now. :/

Edit 1: The contents of Type = AddyBook.get(x) is an object, and the result of .getContactType() is an enumeration.

Comment: Type is null. Now look back in here, `AddyBook.get(x).getContactType();` to see why.

Comment: Where are you populating your AddyBook - it ain't working

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, though. Like I said, I tested that method directly and it works properly.

I'm populating it in another class, and it's working fine.

Comment: @Riqqu: then your testing is bad, seriously bad. Make no assumptions until you find the source of your error. I can guarantee you that `AddyBook.get(x).getContactType();` is returning null for some variable x that you are using when calling the method. Guaranteed.

Comment: This `"Edit 1: The contents of Type = AddyBook.get(x) is an object, and the result of .getContactType() is an enumeration."` tells us nothing. Without code we can make no assumptions. Show code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What code do you need to see? I mean, I can dump everything but that's a LOT of code. I'm sorry. I'm just really new to all this and I'm extremely frustrated with this project.

Comment: You know where the error is since the JVM is telling you the line that is causing the error. You need to check your values of x and find out which values are causing the method that I've mentioned above to return null. Use a debugger if need be, but it's all on your shoulders. And again, assume that no code is correct or has been fully tested because the JVM is telling you otherwise when you run your program.

Comment: @Riqqu See my answer edit for help debugging the problem.

Comment: **Learn what a** `step debugger` **is, and how to use it. There is a perfectly serviceable one in every IDE worth mentioning.**

Comment: Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this line is wrong:

```
if(type.equals(null))
    strTypeList = "What?What?What?LOLOLOLOLOLnopechucktesta";
```

it should be:

```
if(type == null)
    strTypeList = "What?What?What?LOLOLOLOLOLnopechucktesta";
```

Without seeing the contents of the method calls here:

```
Type = AddyBook.get(x).getContactType();
```

it'll be hard to debug but if I were to guess it would be the method "getContactType()" is returning null.

EDIT:

Try unchaining the calls:

Instead of:

```
Type = AddyBook.get(x).getContactType();
strType = Type.toString ( );
```

Try:

```
Entry entry; // I don't actually know what .get() returns
entry = AddyBook.get(x);
if (entry == null)
    throw new RuntimeException("entry is null at "+x+" book size="+AddyBook.size());

Type type = entry.getContactType();
if (type == null)
    throw new RuntimeException("type is null from entry="+entry.toString());

strType = Type.toString ( );
```

Comment: Based on his error messages, I don't think that this can be the problem.

Comment: Also, looking at the docs, `.equals(null)` is supposed to return `false`, not throw a NPE.

Comment: @DennisMeng: `foo.equals(null)` will throw a NPE if the variable calling the method, here foo, is null. So Justin, your point is a good one, but not the cause of his shown exceptions, I don't believe.

Comment: @Riqqu: then your testing is off because the method is in error.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well sure. I was just pointing out that it won't throw an NPE if only the *argument* is null.

Comment: Type is a string, which I've been told you have to use the .equals() method rather than == for equals.

Also, the contents of Type = AddyBook.get(x) is an object, and the result of .getContactType() is an enumeration. I'll edit that into the main post.

Comment: @Riqqu but _if_ Type is null; you cannot call .equals() on a null object.

Comment: Justin: If null, you'll want to also print out the value of x and the value returned by `AddyBook.get(x)`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Good idea. I've updated it.

Comment: And I've updated my comment. Better to just use a debugger though.

Comment: I have no clue how to use the debugger in Eclipse, or I would. I tried earlier and didn't know what I was looking at. :|

Is "Entry entry;" suppose to be whatever .get(x) returns?

Comment: @Riqqu yes, whatever Class get() returns.

Comment: Okay. My derp self used your code, and I think I'm starting to see where the error is. I'm feeling pretty dumb right now. :/

Thanks a ton, though, to everyone!

Comment: @Riqqu No problem. Debugging is a separate skill from programming. But these problems are a lot easier if you use a step debugger. When you get a chance, learn it.