# Why Null Pointer Exception here? Where is the error exactly?

Tags: android, android-layout

I really cannot figure out why am i getting Null pointer exception here. Here is my Java code and XML file.

Any clue?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText Name = new EditText(this);
    Button btnAdd = new Button(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Layout XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Phone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Name"
      />

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/Phone"
       android:text="@string/Add"


       />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:text="@string/Update" />


     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnUpdate"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnUpdate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnUpdate"
        android:text="@string/Delete" />"

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btnSave"
              android:layout_width="70dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnDel"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnDel"
              android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Phone"
              android:text="@string/Save" />        
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: exception stack atleast?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Null Pointer Except, but why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261490/null-pointer-except-but-why)

Answer (score 3):

Move this inside `onCreate`

```
EditText Name;
Button btnAdd; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Name = new EditText(this); // programatically but not added to activity.
    btnAdd = new Button(this);
```

But you have only initialized not added it to root layout or activity.

What you need

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    btnAdd =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
```

Since you already have the `EditText` and `Button` in xml initialize using `findViewById`

Answer (score 0):

Try this : reference view like below:

```
EditText Name;
Button btnAdd;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 Name = (EditText)findviewbyid(R.id.Name);
 btnAdd = (EditText)findviewbyid(R.id.btnAdd);

}
```

instead of:

```
EditText Name = new EditText(this);
Button btnAdd = new Button(this);
```